# Certain system graphics missing

Tags: graphics, themes, 17.04, settings

Ever since I updated to 17.04, certain system graphics have been missing (ex. slider bars, outlines around text boxes, boxes around confirm buttons, etc.)

I have no knowledge of any commands that can be used to fix this, can anyone help me?

EDIT: If you look in the settings window, you'll see that all the sliders and buttons are missing. That is my problem.

[image: Settings window]

Comment: Please try to [reset the Unity configuration](/a/202020/175814) (refer to the part about 14.04 and above).

Comment: Resetting the desktop configuration likely would help. What theme are you using? With themes generally they are only compatible with certain versions of GTK, so you just need to update the theme to the right version.

Comment: @Wilf I was using the arc-darker theme, i changed it to the default theme and it fixed the problem. I want to keep using the arc theme, but since it doesnt support 17.04, ii guess i'll have to use another one for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the Arc theme directly [from Github](https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme/) if you are sure it is out of date. The packaged versions [from there](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/) haven't been updated but you can build if from source if you follow the instructions there.

If you are using [the repository's packaged version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/arc-theme) and are sure you didn't originally get the theme from Github or similar, I would recommend reporting a bug first though.